# Why animals other than Goat, Chicken and pigs are not given as animal sacrfice?

Tags: temple, practice, animals, sacrifice

- Goats, roosters and pigs are given as sacrifice to gods.
- There are also many other animals and birds living but they are not Sacrificed.

**QUESTION :**

- Why certain animals like Goat, roosters, pigs are given as animal sacrifice and others NOT ?

Comment: Pigs? Where are pigs sacrificed?

Comment: Generally Domesticated animals such as these  are mainey used , humans breed them in large number's  they are available throughout the world. so sacrificing the old stock won't affect there population in nature.They are much less wild and after sacrificing humans can eat them as a food . Besides of these some elaborate sacrifices like in Ashvamedha horse was used.

Comment: @TheDestroyer friend There is temple for Anamar they are two brothers and thier life story tells they killed a Pig(Gigantic) in his enemy country so now also the temple dedicated to them will sarifice Pigs

Comment: Are you serious Bulls, Buffalos, and Horses are sacrificed in Yagnas.

Comment: @@Sakthi There are many other animals which can be offered for sacrifice. I can post an answer but i really don't feel like doing so. So, your question is not valid. Hence you can remove the bounty from it.

Comment: @Rickross How can one remove bounty I dont know

Comment: @Sakthi Bounty can't be removed. I was not aware of that. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many more animals other than the ones mentioned in the question, that can be sacrificed. Sacrificing animals for both Gods and Manes is prescribed in scriptures.

The Manu Smriti mentions the following animals that can be offered to manes:

> 3.266. I will now fully declare what kind of sacrificial food, given to the manes according to the rule, will serve for a long time or for
>   eternity.
>
> 3.267. The ancestors of men are satisfied for one month with sesamum grains, rice, barley, masha beans, water, roots, and fruits, which
>   have been given according to the prescribed rule,
>
> 3.268. Two months with fish, three months with the meat of gazelles, four with mutton, and five indeed with the flesh of birds,
>
> 3.270. Ten months they are satisfied with the meat of boars and buffaloes, but eleven months indeed with that of hares and tortoises,

And what kind of meat can be offered to Gods is mentioned in the following verse of the KulArnava Tantram:

> MAmsantu Tribidham Proktam Kha-Bhu-Jalacharam Priye |
>   YathAsambhavampekyam TarpanArtham Prakalpayeth ||
>
> .............
>
> The meat is of three kinds ; obtained from animals that fly , that walk
>   on earth and that live in water. For the gratification of deity anyone of them
>   has to be arranged.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 5-44.**

However, i need to reiterate here that killing is only allowed for the sake of Devas and Pitrus. If its done without sacrifice and for our own gratification then that is a sin as stated in the following verse:

> Pitridevatayajneshu VaidhahimsA Vidhiyathe | ATmArtham PrAninAm HimsA
>   KadAchinnoditA Priye ||
>
> ........
>
> Killing is legal in sacrifices for manes and gods. Priye, but no
>   scriptures ever allow doing the same for one's own pleasure.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 5-45.**